# Facing issues due to ownership on mounted folder with Docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, openproject

Following command works fine

```sh
sudo docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name openproject -e SECRET_KEY_BASE=somesecret \
      -v /var/lib/openproject/pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main \
        -v /var/lib/openproject/logs:/var/log/supervisor \
          -v /var/lib/openproject/static:/var/db/openproject \
            openproject/community:8
```

But this command doesn't start container

```sh
sudo docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name openproject -e SECRET_KEY_BASE=somesecret \
      -v ~/Dropbox/openproject/pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main \
        -v /var/lib/openproject/logs:/var/log/supervisor \
          -v ~/Dropbox/openproject/static:/var/db/openproject \
            openproject/community:8
```

I've also tried making `/var/lib/openproject/pgdata` symlink to `~/Dropbox/openproject/pgdata`. But it also didn't work.

Docker logs say, `PostgreSQL Config owner (postgres:102) and data owner (app:1000) do not match, and config owner is not root`.

Is there any way to mount non-root folder on root folder inside the docker container and solve this issue?

Comment: Can you please add error you are getting and does ~/Dropbox/openproject/pgdata,  ~/Dropbox/openproject/logs and ~/Dropbox/openproject/static exist?

Comment: docker logs say, "PostgreSQL Config owner (postgres:102) and data owner (app:1000) do not match, and config owner is not root". looks like the folder that I created must be owned by root only. But in that condition I'll fail them to sync. :(